# Changing Links with Loops

Tags: vba, excel, loops

```
For x = 1 To 40

    objIE.navigate "http://example.com/market/search?appid=578080#pX_name_asc" '---> here is pX_name_asc
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    MsgBox "Check Point 1"

    y = 1
    For Each itemEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_row_link")
        Prc1 = itemEle.getElementsByClassName("market_listing_item_name_block")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).textContent
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & y).Value = Prc1
        y = y + 1
    Next

Next x
```

I just what to change `objIE.navigate "http://example.com/market/search?appid=578080#pX_name_asc"` like   `p1_name_asc`, `p2_name_asc`, ..., `p40_name_asc`

I tried use `For … Next` loop (as you see on top) for changing link but I think it's not working for changing links :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stitch *x* into the url string with basic string concatenation.

```
objIE.navigate "http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=578080#p" & x & "_name_asc"
```

Comment: it works thank you so much but when link changing,  **for each** starts again at cell 1. what should i do

Comment: It looks like you should move y = 1 up above For x = 1 To 40.